# Need help with windows WSL

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm completely new to this windows WSL for Linux so please don't mind the silly questions. I'm using WSL and I'm not able to use the Wi-Fi card of my laptop through Ubuntu or Kali terminal. How can I use it?

1. I used `ifconfig` and it showed:
   [image]
2. I used `iw` and it showed me this, even though there is a wifi connection available.
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices are still handled by Windows. So your wifi card should be available in Windows device manager and its drivers added there. Then it can be used by WSL to access the Internet for example.

Imagine like eth0 you see in `ifconfig` output. You didn't added in anyway eth0 in WSL, did you? It's available in Windows and presented to WSL.